# SonarQube partial import

Tags: sonarqube

I have several .lcov coverage report files and I want import my reports in several steps (using TeamCity SonarQube runner) in same SonarQube project.

But every import step replacing all coverage information in SonarQube project, not adding new data

How can I partial add coverage information to my project without losing previous information?

Parameters, I passing to SonarQube runner:

```
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
-Dsonar.language=js
-Dsonar.javascript.lov.reportsPaths=path_to_my_lcov_report
-X
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to produce a complete LCOV report and feed that to the analysis.

Analysing a project "replaces" all previous results: SonarQube then allows you to check how metrics such as coverage evolved over time.